# ansible/yaml : get value as string from dict

Tags: python, list, ansible, yaml

I've got some variables I need to loop on :

```
mariadb_grants:
  "*.*":
    - user1: "ALL, SELECT"
    - user2: "ALL"
  "toto":
    - user1: "ALL"
    - user23: "GRANT"
```

Of course, userX is not defined in advance, I can have user1233 etc.
I can loop through the dict fairly easily with this code :

```
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "Key is {{ item }} and value is {{ mariadb_grants[item] }}"
      loop: "{{ mariadb_grants.keys() }}"
```

I got this :

```
ok: [localhost] => (item=*.*) => {}

MSG:

Key is *.* and value is [{'user1': 'ALL, SELECT'}, {'user2': 'ALL'}]
ok: [localhost] => (item=toto) => {}

MSG:

Key is toto and value is [{'user1': 'ALL'}, {'user23': 'GRANT'}]
```

The thing I'm trying to do, is just get the key and values of userx, basically I want this :

```
My key is *.* I'm user1 and my value is "ALL, SELECT"
My key is *.* I'm user2 and my value is ALL
My key is "toto" I'm user1 and my value is ALL
[...]
```

It seems I can't loop through my subelements :(

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use *dict2items* inside the *with_subelements* loop, e.g.

```yaml
  - debug:
      msg: 'My key is {{ item.0.key }} I am {{ key }} and my value is "{{ val }}"'
    with_subelements:
      - "{{ mariadb_grants|dict2items }}"
      - value
    vars:
      key: "{{ item.1.keys()|first }}"
      val: "{{ item.1.values()|first }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: My key is *.* I am user1 and my value is "ALL, SELECT"
  msg: My key is *.* I am user2 and my value is "ALL"
  msg: My key is toto I am user1 and my value is "ALL"
  msg: My key is toto I am user23 and my value is "GRANT"
```